# Can't run a JAR in AWS EC2 linux server

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, executable-jar

I'm trying to run a JAR in my aws ec2 linux instance.
The instance has Java 11 and Javac 11 as well.
I downloaded the JAR locally to make sure it's runnable, it worked (on my machine).
But when I run the JAR inside the instance I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile spring-petclinic-2.4.2.jar
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What command are you running to execute the Jar? Are your local/EC2 machines running the same version of the JVM? If you pass the -`verbose` flag do you get a more useful error message?

Comment: how did you download the jar file? are you sure you downloaded a .jar extension not an HTML?

Comment: @MisterSmith The command is `java -jar JAR_NAME.jar`

Comment: @KamèlRomdhani Sure thing, I copied the JAR file from an S3 bucket using the AWS CLI., and yes, It is a JAR file and not HTML.